# Simple password compare using crypt in C

Tags: c, unix, cryptography

I read the first password from the user and encrypted it. Then I read a second password and encrypted it. I then compared the two encrypted passwords, but the comparison always states they're equal. I narrowed the problem to this: After the second encryption, the `password` and `guess` variables have the same value. This is a strange error; can anyone provide insight and/or a fix?

Thank you in advance. The code:

```
int main(void)
{
  char salt[] = "00";
  char *password;
  char *guess;

  password = crypt(getpass("Enter Password1:"), salt);
  printf("password = %s\n", password);

  guess = crypt(getpass("Enter Password2:"), salt);
  printf("password = %s\n", password);
  printf("guess = %s\n", guess);

  puts(strcmp(guess, password) == 0
       ? "Access Granted." : "Access Denied.");

  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Enter Password1:
password = 007XN7q4UF/o6
Enter Password2:
password = 00MqrTyK65aEA
guess = 00MqrTyK65aEA
Access Granted.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the manpage for `crypt`, it returns a pointer to a static buffer.

You'll have to copy both `guess` and `password`:

```
password = strdup(crypt(getpass("Enter Password1:"), salt));
...
guess = strdup(crypt(getpass("Enter Password2:"), salt));
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. I thought I had ruled out getpass() as the culprit but there must have been an additional error at the time.

Answer (score 4):

Make a copy (`strcopy` or `strdup`) of the value returned by `crypt`.

From the manpage for [`crypt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt):

> The return value points to static data whose content is overwritten by each call.

```
password = strdup(crypt(getpass("Enter Password1:"), salt));
...
guess = strdup(crypt(getpass("Enter Password2:"), salt));
...
free(guess);
free(password);
```

Alternatively, you can use the less portable `crypt_r` which allows you to specify a structure that contains a buffer which is not static (and that you do not have to free explicitly if allocated on the stack as shown below):

```
crypt_data password_data = { 0 };
crypt_data guess_data = { 0 };
...
password = crypt_r(getpass("Enter Password1:"), salt, &password_data);
...
guess = crypt_r(getpass("Enter Password2:"), salt, &guess_data);
```

Note that each `crypt_data` structure consumes around 128kB of memory though, which is excessive for your needs; `crypt_r`'s main audience are multi-threaded applicatiosn that may call `crypt` concurrently.